# Bumping Series Implementation

Tags: sequence, subsequence, fastest-algorithm

I have a follow-up question here from my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4646752/bumping-series-and-its-formula) on Math SE. I am lazy enough to explain the content again, so I have used a paraphraser to explain it below:

I was considering arbitrary series, springing up as a top priority, when I considered one potential series in my mind. It is as per the following:

[image]

The essential thought is, take a line of regular numbers \$\mathbb{N}\$ which goes till boundlessness, and add them. Something apparent here is that the most greatest biggest number \$\mathbb{N}_{max}\$ would be \$\mathbb{N}_{i}\$. In essential words, on the off chance that we go till number 5, \$\mathbb{N}_5\$ the level it comes to by summation is 5.

Further, continuing, we can get:

[image: image1]

The essential ramifications here is that we knock the numbers by unambiguous \$\mathbb{N}\$. At start, we take the starting number, for our situation it is 1, we move once up and afterward once down. Then we do it two times, threefold, etc. So `1 3 2` as per my outline is one knock. At the closure \$\mathbb{N}\$ which is 2 here, we will hop it by 2 and make it low by 2. So it gets `2 5 12 7 4`. Here, expect \$\mathbb{N}_i\$ as the quantity of incrementation, before it was 1, presently it is 2. We get various sets, with various terms, however absolute number of terms we overcome this would be \$2 \mathbb{N}_i + 1\$. Presently, it will begin from 4, continue taking 3 leaps prior to arriving by three terms. By this, we get series featured by circles in that three-sided exhibit as:

```
1, 3, 2, 5, 12, 7, 4, 9, 20, 44, 24, 13, 7, 15, 32, 68, 144, 76, 40, 21, 11, 23, 48, 100, 208, 432, 224, 116, 60, 31, 16...
```

The series appear to be disparate, my particular inquiry this is the way to address this series in Numerical terms.

Challenge: Implement the algorithm which can build this series.

Scoring Criteria: It is ranked by fastest-algorithm so the answer with lowest time complexity is considered (time complexity is loosely allowed to be anywhere) but the program must have been running accurate result.

Comment: ["serie gan tot oneindig" means "series goes to infinity"](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=serie%20gaan%20tot%20oneindig&op=translate) and ["verhoging en afname met 1" means "increase and decrease by 1"](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=verhoging%20en%20afname%20met%201&op=translate)

Comment: Sorry, I used camscanner to do it from my diary, I write it in dutch and would even prefer using a dutch Q&A site

Comment: ChatGPT or even Google translate would probably help you write a clearer post in English.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
ＮθＩ⊘×⊕θＸ²↔⁻θ⊕×⊖⌈₂θ⌈₂θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYyxDgIhEER7v4JySbCxM1eZs/AKzUX9AQ43SgLLAcv5@UhijDZO@WbemIdOJmhX60Bz4VPxEyaIsluNyRJDrzPDQbsFb3C1HjMMZBJ6JG4kSiXG8GzGRondlIMrjHC0VDJEJX6nb3mPX9KjdZbucIlFJzyHwO1Ptsc/xSddrdu6XtwL) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the `n`th term. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ                      First input as a number
      θ                 First input
     ⊕                  Incremented
    ×                   Multiplied by
        ²               Literal integer `2`
       Ｘ                Raised to power
           θ            First input
         ↔⁻             Absolute difference with
                 θ      First input
                ₂       Square root
               ⌈        Ceiling
              ⊖         Decremented
             ×          Multiplied by
                    θ   First input
                   ₂    Square root
                  ⌈     Ceiling
   ⊘                    Halved
  Ｉ                     Cast to string
```

30 bytes in integer arithmetic:

```
ＮθＩ⊘×⊕θＸ²↔⁻θ⊕×⊖⌈₂θ⌈₂θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5NDoIwEIX3nqLLNqmJsGVFJDEsMCy8QIGJnaQUbKdw/FpEI7Oan@@9N71Wrp@UibG2c6B7GDtw/CWKU@k9Pi3PJNNpWjUaYPzmQNEGSNZOa2q0ZLkQgjVq/gpq2zsYwRIMu7R1aIlflad0owoXHIA/cAR/ZFPmzzOXrOz8ZAIBb9AGv8Ud0V1cwX@jxZb1qf2hIsbsEs@LeQM) Link is to verbose version of code.

Comment: @AiraThunberg I derived it myself without looking anything up so for all I know it may only be an independent rediscovery.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

Port of [Neil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258377/53748) (I was working towards it myself but he nailed it).

Unsure of the complexity of this closed-form formula, but *think* it is \$O(M(B(n))B(n))\$ where \$n\$ is the input, \$M(x)\$ is the multiplication of two \$x\$ bit numbers and \$B(x)\$ is the bit-length of \$x\$.

```
½Ċ’×$‘ạ⁸’2*×‘
```

A monadic Link that accepts \$n\$ and yields \$a(n)\$.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q3iNdjxpmHp6u8qhhxsNdCx817gByjbQOTwfy/@scbs961DBHwdZO4VHDXM3I//9zMotLNIoS89JTNQx1FEwMNTUVtBWiDQ0MdBSABJQCIR0FUxiIBQA)**

#### How?

```
½Ċ’×$‘ạ⁸’2*×‘ - Link: positive integer, n
½             - square-root
 Ċ            - ceiling
    $         - last two links as a monad - f(x=that):
  ’           -   decrement (x)
   ×          -   (that) multiply (x)
     ‘        - increment (that) -> A
       ⁸      - chain's left argument = n
      ạ       - (A) absolute difference (n)
        ’     - decrement (that) -> E
         2    - two
          *   - (2) exponentiate (E)
           ×  - (that) multiply (n)
            ‘ - increment
```

---

To avoid floating point arithmetic we could instead do it in  <s>17 16</s>  14 bytes (-2 thanks to Neil!):

```
’Æ½‘×$‘ạ⁸2*×‘H
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9w26G98UBi06OGGYenqwDJh7sWPmrcYaR1eDqQ4/Ff53B71qOGOQq2dgqPGuZqRv7/n5NZXKJRlJiXnqphqKNgYqipqaCtEG1oYKCjACSgFAjpKJjCQCwA)**

This replaces `½Ċ’×$` with `’Æ½‘×$` and moves the decrement out of the exponent, instead halving at the end (`H`).

```
’Æ½‘×$ - chain: integer n
’      - decrement -> n-1
 Æ½    - integer-square-root (n-1) (uses only integer arithmetic)
     $ - last two links as a monad - f(x=that):
   ‘   -   increment (x)
    ×  -   (that) multiply (x)
```

Comment: square-root ceiling decrement is the same as decrement square-root floor for positive integer n which doesn't make a difference in floating point but in integer it should save you some bytes.

Comment: (just tried it and `’Æ½‘×$‘ạ⁸2*×‘H` seems to work for 14 bytes)

Comment: Thanks @Neil! Yeah, that is a valid simplification.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 97 + 3 bytes

+3 bytes from `-lm`. Runs in O(n) time, where n is the index.

```c
f(M,n,v,l,c){l=0;for(n=c=1;M--;l+=v&&v--?:-1)n=((v=l?v:c++)?2*n:n/2+.5)+pow(2,v?l:l-2);return n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU3BDoIwFLvzFS8kkje3KSzxwlz4Av/AC5mOkIyHQZ0Hwq87B7GHNmmb1srO2hgdXgSJILywbPam1G6ckIw1lb5IqT03oSiClE0tK0YGMRjfhNpyzhq1p5qOih9OjD/GDyoRGl97qZie7q/3REB6iT29YGh7QgZzBgnpAXB1ezBQ6iRnUKumzX9lxWNKHYf57nalXIDDnjG9pcvG/4tSZ0v8Wufb7hmlH34)

Comment: Flags don't count for extra bytes anymore, so this is just 96

Comment: Suggest `l-!v*2` instead of `v?l:l-2`

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
tîD<*-<ÄoI>*;
```

Another port of [*@Neil*'s Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258377/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/5PA6FxstXZvDLfmedlrW//9bAgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W9s5O5nr6TwqG2SgpK9n8v/ksPrXGy0dG0Ot@T72WlZ/9f5DwA).
<sub>The TIO-links use the legacy version of 05AB1E, because the regular 05AB1E on TIO is out-of-date, and still contains [an already fixed bug when using `o` on decimal values ending with `.0`](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/issues/196).</sub>

**Explanation:**

Basically implements the formula found by *@Neil*:

$$a(n) = \frac{(n+1)\times 2^{\left|n-\left\lceil\sqrt{n}\right\rceil\times(\left\lceil\sqrt{n}\right\rceil-1)-1\right|}}{2}$$

```python
t              # Get the square root of the (implicit) input-integer
 î             # Ceil it
  D            # Duplicate it
   <           # Decrease the copy by 1
    *          # Multiply the two together
     -         # Subtract this from the (implicit) input-integer
      <        # Decrease that by 1
       Ä       # Get the absolute value of that
        o      # Take 2 to the power that
         I>    # Push the input+1
           *   # Multiply the two together
            ;  # Halve it
               # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 53 bytes

Formula:

$$
f(n)=\frac{(n+1) \times 2^{|n-\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil \times(\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil-1)-1|}}{2}
$$

```
f=((#+1)*2^Abs[#-⌈Sqrt@#⌉*(⌈Sqrt@#⌉-1)-1])/2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z/NVkNDWdtQU8sozjGpOFpZ91FPR3BhUYmD8qOeTi0NZJ6uoaauYaymvpHa/5DEpJzU6LTovFid6jwdQx1Dg9pYff2Aosy8kv8A)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 49 bytes

Port of [Neil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258377/53748)

```
n=>-~n*2**~-Math.abs(n+(c=(n**=.5)%1?~n:-n)*~c-1)
```

Formula:

$$
f(n) = \frac{(n+1)\times 2^{\left|n-\left\lceil\sqrt{n}\right\rceil\times(\left\lceil\sqrt{n}\right\rceil-1)-1\right|}}{2}
$$

Try it:

```js
f=n=>-~n*2**~-Math.abs(n+(c=(n**=.5)%1?~n:-n)*~c-1)

for(i=0;i<20;)console.log(f(++i))
```

### Upd 54 -> 49

Thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld) for the [tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258357/bumping-series-implementation/258868?noredirect=1#comment571122_258868) to reduce bytes count

Comment: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoMwDADQ0wySlBQV9qOLnmCH6DrrOiQRK/vs1bv3vuEXSjzzcbHae21JmsrMVWkgqvwM18eHVwF1EAWUSPwdb/1SdWRFqpF7bMlOyNJN@TF0E0bTYvvqd9sggXMZsf0B)